# Making S3 static web hosting content private

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to be able to publish test reports to S3 and have it accessible to the URL sent at the end of the Drone build.

Is it possible to have the S3 static site not view-able by anyone? So its only accessible by people who can already access resources in the VPC using a VPN.

I read that the content must have public read access, so checking if that is avoidable.

Answer (score 17):

Yes:

- Set up the static website as normal,
- Add a VPC endpoint for S3,
- Use a bucket policy to deny all but traffic from your VPC.

Here is a good article describing it in more detail: https://blog.monsterxx03.com/2017/08/19/build-private-staticwebsite-on-s3/

Comment: great answer.. really helpful.

Comment: Does this require Block Public Access to be disabled?

Comment: The article doesn't discuss how to set up an VPC endpoint to a bucket

Comment: @arunvelsriram No, you should enable `Block Public Access`

Comment: @Cybernetic Here is the tutorial that talks about how to set up an VPC endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#create-gateway-endpoint-s3